# A specific collection of subgraphs in $K_{70, 70}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

> Does there exist a collection of subgraphs $\{\Gamma_i\}_{i = 1}^{24}$ of $K_{70, 70}$, that satisfy the following two properties:
>
> 1)$\Gamma_i \cong K_{i, i} \forall 1 \leq i \leq 24$;
>
> 2)Any edge of $K_{70, 70}$ belongs to exactly one subgraph from this collection?

This question appeared because, the $K_{n, n}$ always has $n^2$ vertices, and $70^2 = \Sigma_{i = 1}^{24} i^2$. Thus the numbers of edges here match perfectly. But that is clearly not enough...

Both the initial graph and the collection of subgraphs are too large to solve this question via brute force. And I do not know any other way to approach this problem.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why the graph theoretic setup is relevant.  If you had a suitable collection of 70 partitions of 70 (i.e., exactly one 1 in the 70 partitions, exactly two 2s, etc. up to 24) you could build such a decomposition.  Conversely, looking at one of the sets of 70 vertices in the $K_{70,70}$ gives you such a decomposition; in fact given any two such sets of partitions you can construct a decomposition of the $K_{70,70}$.  It's not clear to me whether this partition problem is amenable to a realistic amount of brute force, but it is certainly not _less_ amenable to brute force.

Comment: This is a discrete version of the "squaring the square" problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square

Comment: Maybe some of the techniques used here can be helpful: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/jcd.3180030608

Comment: @dvitek: I do not see how to construct a required partition from 70 partitions (the first part of your comment). Could you clarify?

Comment: @IlyaBogdanov I have expanded in an answer below; let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: It seems I asked the same question at math.SE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407387/does-k-70-70-decompose-into-subgraphs-isomorphic-to-k-1-1-through-k-24).  I'm interested in the question, because I want to know if there's a $70 \times 70$ Latin square that decomposes into subsquares of orders $1$ through $24$, and the existence of this graph decomposition is a prerequisite.

Comment: Yanior Weg, I won't be surprised if Rob provides a solution soon (unless there is none) but at the moment there is no solution.  If you "accept" an answer which doesn't solve the problem, you discourage other people from looking at the problem. So I strongly recommend that you unaccept the answer so that this great question is still marked as unsolved.

Comment: An answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875570/is-it-possible-to-cover-a-70-times70-square-with-24-squares-with-side-length) claims it is impossible.

Comment: @RobPratt I don't see how your link is relevant.  The OP's question is far broader than tiling a 70-by-70 rectangle with square tiles; in particular, the consecutivity-requirement of the tiling is not present in the graph-theory question.

Comment: @dvitek Given a graph decomposition into complete bipartite subgraphs, it seems like you can permute the rows and columns of the colored biadjacency matrix so that the entries of the same color are contiguous.

Comment: @RobPratt I don't understand the coloring part of your answer.  Sure, you can do this for e.g. the 24x24 subgraph, then the 23x23 and 22x22.  But at some point you end up with a very complicated system of contiguity requirements and I'm not sure that there's a simple argument that such a thing has a solution.

Comment: The “colors” are just 1 to 24, indicating which subgraph each edge belongs to. I haven’t worked out the details, but the process I was thinking of is to proceed row by row and then column by column.  For row 1, permute the columns to group all entries of the same color. Do the same thing for row 2, while preserving the groups in row 1, etc.

Answer (score 3):

This is an expanded version of my comment on the question, per Ilya Bogdanov's request.

Suppose that we have such a decomposition of $K_{70,70}$.  Fix some vertex $v$ (say in the left half) and consider all the 70 edges of $v$.  If $v \in V(\Gamma_{24})$, then 24 of these edges come from the $\Gamma_{24}$.  In general we know that $$\{i | v \in V(\Gamma_i) \}$$ is a partition - call it $P(v_i)$ - of 70.  Furthermore, this partition has no repeated parts.

So for each $v_i, 1 \le i \le 70$, we get a partition $P(v_i)$ of 70; call this collection $\mathcal{P}$.  As a whole, the multiset $$\bigcup \mathcal{P} = P(v_1) \cup P(v_2) \cup \cdots \cup P(v_{70})$$ must contain exactly one 1, exactly two 2s, and so on up to exactly twenty-four 24s.

Hence, given such a decomposition we get a system of partitions as described (i.e., the appropriate number of 1s, 2s, etc. and no repeated parts).  Note that this system corresponds to the left half of the vertices; we will get another system (<s>possibly</s> **definitely** different) if we look at the right half of the vertices.

**EDIT, following Ilya's and Aaron's comments.** In order for the graph to be a simple $K_{70,70}$, and not just a 70-regular bipartite graph, it is necessary that the left and right partitions have the following property: if $1 \le i, j \le 24$ occur in the same partition in the left system $\mathcal{L}$,  then no partition in $\mathcal{R}$ contains both $i$ and $j$.

---

<s>Now we show the converse: given such a system, we can construct a decomposition of the $K_{70,70}$.  For ease of exposition, we will assume that we have two such systems $\mathcal{L}$ and $\mathcal{R}$; it will be clear that we can take $\mathcal{L} = \mathcal{R}$ so one such system will suffice.</s>

We need to specify which vertices are in the $\Gamma_i$; this suffices as the $\Gamma_i$ are induced subgraphs of the $K_{70,70}$.  But this is straightforward: the vertices that are in the left half of $\Gamma_i$ are the partitions in the partition system $\mathcal{L}$ that contain $i$, and similarly for the right half and $\mathcal{R}$.

---

The existence of such a partition system is a necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of such a decomposition of $K_{70,70}$.  It is clear that this is combinatorially simpler than thinking about the subgraphs themselves; in particular there are fewer than 30000 partitions of 70 with distinct parts, and probably substantially fewer with no 1s or 2s (which at least 67 of the 70 partitions must have).  It's still not possible to naively exhaust, but oh well.

Comment: There are 14136 partitions in total, of which 3907 have no 1 or 2.  More can be said about how the partitions fit together but I also don't see a plausible exhaustive search here.

Comment: So, let one of partitions start with $24+13+\dots$ --- both for some vertex $v$ in one part and for some vertex $u$ in the other. Then the edge $uv$ lies in both $\Gamma_{24}$ and $\Gamma_{13}$... (Sorry for incomprehensible form of the previous version of the comment.)

Comment: I think your construction will give a bipartite multigraph, regular of degree $70.$ To be a simple graph it would be necessary that a partition on the left and a partition on the right share at most one common member. Is that possible? It would seem promising to have large overlaps on each side such as $24+18+15+13$ repeated $13$ times on the left and $24+20+16+12$ repeated $12$ times on the right. But then none of the other $11$ on the right with a $24$ could use $20,16$ or $12.$

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz Oops, yes, that's correct.  I will edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments about finding 70 partitions of 70 into distinct parts, with part $j$ appearing $j$ times among all partitions, I came up with an alternate integer linear programming formulation and found a solution.  Let $P$ be the set of all (14136) partitions of 70 into distinct parts of size at most 24.  For $j \in \{1,\dots,24\}$, let $P_j \subset P$ be the subset of partitions that contain part $j$. Let binary decision variable $x_p$ indicate whether partition $p\in P$ is used.  The problem is to find a feasible solution to the following constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{p\in P} x_p &= 70 \\
\sum_{p\in P_j} x_p &= j &&\text{for $j \in \{1,\dots,24\}$} \\
x_p &\in \{0,1\} && \text{for $p\in P$}
\end{align}

Here's one such solution:

```
{1,2,5,7,10,13,15,17}
{2,3,4,6,8,14,16,17}
{3,6,16,21,24}
{3,7,8,16,17,19}
{4,9,11,22,24}
{4,19,23,24}
{4,21,22,23}
{5,6,12,23,24}
{5,18,23,24}
{5,19,22,24}
{5,20,21,24}
{6,18,22,24}
{6,19,22,23}
{6,20,21,23}
{7,16,23,24}
{7,17,22,24}
{7,19,20,24}
{7,19,21,23}
{7,20,21,22}
{8,9,10,19,24}
{8,9,10,20,23}
{8,9,10,21,22}
{8,9,16,17,20}
{8,10,11,19,22}
{8,10,11,20,21}
{9,10,11,17,23}
{9,14,23,24}
{9,17,20,24}
{9,17,21,23}
{10,17,21,22}
{10,18,19,23}
{10,18,20,22}
{11,12,23,24}
{11,13,22,24}
{11,15,21,23}
{11,17,18,24}
{11,17,20,22}
{11,18,19,22}
{11,18,20,21}
{12,14,20,24}
{12,14,21,23}
{12,15,19,24}
{12,15,20,23}
{12,15,21,22}
{12,16,18,24}
{12,16,19,23}
{12,16,20,22}
{12,17,18,23}
{12,18,19,21}
{13,14,19,24}
{13,14,20,23}
{13,14,21,22}
{13,15,18,24}
{13,15,19,23}
{13,15,20,22}
{13,16,17,24}
{13,16,18,23}
{13,16,19,22}
{13,16,20,21}
{13,18,19,20}
{14,15,17,24}
{14,15,18,23}
{14,15,19,22}
{14,15,20,21}
{14,16,18,22}
{14,16,19,21}
{14,17,18,21}
{15,16,17,22}
{15,16,18,21}
{15,17,18,20}
```

**Edit**: Here's an updated formulation that captures both left ($i=1$) and right ($i=2$) sides and the rule that prevents the same pair $\{j,k\}$ from appearing together on both sides:
\begin{align}
\sum_{p\in P} x_{i,p} &= 70 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,2\}$} \\
\sum_{p\in P_j} x_{i,p} &= j &&\text{for $i\in\{1,2\}$ and $j \in \{1,\dots,24\}$} \\
\sum_{p\in P_j \cap P_k} x_{i,p} &\le j\ y_{i,j,k} && \text{for $i\in\{1,2\}$ and $1 \le j<k \le 24$} \\
y_{1,j,k} + y_{2,j,k} &\le 1 &&\text{for $1 \le j<k \le 24$} \\
x_{i,p} &\in [0,70] \cap \mathbb{Z} && \text{for $i\in\{1,2\}$ and $p\in P$} \\
y_{i,j,k} &\in \{0,1\} && \text{for $i\in\{1,2\}$ and $1 \le j<k \le 24$}
\end{align}

Comment: I see the 70 partitions corresponding to the vertices on one side of the $K_{70,70}$, but I don't see how to make a partition of $K_{70,70}$ out of them.

Comment: Hmm, I guess after the edits to @dvitek's answer we need two such sets of partitions, with no pair of parts appearing together on both sides?

Comment: Yes, that should do it.

Comment: @RobPratt What software are you using to do the integer linear programming?

Comment: I am using [SAS](http://support.sas.com/documentation/onlinedoc/or/).

Comment: I'm puzzled.  Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet, just proposing a formulation that captures the problem.

Comment: Notice that you can use the same partition of $70$ several times (for several vertices in one part); so I do not understand why you put $x_i\in\{0,1\}$. Moreover, by these reasons, the second half of your inequalities should be more complicated.

Comment: Updated just now and will rerun the solver.

Comment: Can you show the lists of vertices?

Comment: From your first list (left hand side) I see that 24 appears with every other number except $1,2,22,23.$ (That was one eyeballing of the answer so I might be off a bit.) To find $70$ lists for the right hand side which mesh with these would require (along with much more) $24$ partitions of $70$ using just $1,22,23,24.$ That won’t work with just a single $1$. If there is a solution it would need an abundance of multiple lists (vertices) on each side with exactly the same members (neighbors on the other side).

Answer (score 0):

You can use integer linear programming instead of brute force.
Let decision variables $x_{i,c}$ and $y_{j,c}$ indicate whether left node $i$ and right node $j$ appear in $\Gamma_c$, respectively, and let decision variable $z_{i,j,c}$ indicate whether edge $(i,j)$ appears in $\Gamma_c$.  Then the problem is to find a feasible solution to the following linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{70} x_{i,c} &= c &&\text{for $c\in\{1,\dots,24\}$} \\
\sum_{j=1}^{70} y_{j,c} &= c &&\text{for $c\in\{1,\dots,24\}$} \\
\sum_{j=1}^{70} z_{i,j,c} &= c\ x_{i,c} &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,70\}$, $c\in\{1,\dots,24\}$} \\
\sum_{i=1}^{70} z_{i,j,c} &= c\ y_{j,c} &&\text{for $j\in\{1,\dots,70\}$, $c\in\{1,\dots,24\}$} \\
\sum_{c=1}^{24} z_{i,j,c} &= 1 &&\text{for $i,j\in\{1,\dots,70\}$} \\
z_{i,j,c} &\le x_{i,c} &&\text{for $i,j\in\{1,\dots,70\}$, $c\in\{1,\dots,24\}$}\\
z_{i,j,c} &\le y_{j,c} &&\text{for $i,j\in\{1,\dots,70\}$, $c\in\{1,\dots,24\}$}\\
z_{i,j,c} &\ge x_{i,c} + y_{j,c} - 1 &&\text{for $i,j\in\{1,\dots,70\}$, $c\in\{1,\dots,24\}$}\\
x_{i,c} &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,70\}$, $c\in\{1,\dots,24\}$}\\
y_{j,c} &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for $j\in\{1,\dots,70\}$, $c\in\{1,\dots,24\}$} \\
z_{i,j,c} &\in \{0,1\} &&\text{for $i,j\in\{1,\dots,70\}$, $c\in\{1,\dots,24\}$} 
\end{align}

Comment: If there is a solution, it might be found quickly.  If there isn't a solution, you'd better hope that the software has exceptionally good symmetry breaking to cope with the $(70!)^2$ symmetry.

Comment: Modern integer linear programming solvers do handle such symmetry automatically, but I found a solution by using a different formulation, which I'll post as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like the idea of @dvitek to use pairs of multisets of partitions as a data structure for these $K_{70,70}$ decompositions. Let me repeat the idea since it partly lives in comments.

A $K_{70,70}$ decomposition is equivalent to a particular pair $\{\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}\}$ where each of $\mathcal{A,B}$ is a multiset of $70$ partitions into distinct parts of $70.$

Each particular edge belongs to a $K_{ii}$ for some $i.$ Label that edge $i.$ Assign each vertex the set consisting of the labels of its incident edges. This is a partition of $70.$ Finally,  let $\mathcal{A,B}$ be the multisets of partitions corresponding to the two vertex classes. The following properties are satisfied:

- Among the $70$ partitions in $\mathcal{A},$ an integer $i \leq 24$ appears  $i$ times and similarly for $\mathcal{B}.$
- Two partitions $\alpha,\beta$ one each from $\mathcal{A,B}$ can share at most one member. Equivalently, there is a partial edge coloring of $K_n$ using Amber and Blue so that two integers appear together in a partition $\alpha \in \mathcal{A}$ only if the corresponding edge of $K_n$ is Amber.

The converse is also true. Given such a pair of multisets of partitions, a $K_{70,70}$ decomposition is determined.

Given the second requirement, it seems that (most of) the partitions would use  relatively few parts and occur to high multiplicity.

For example,  perhaps $\mathcal{A}$ would use $24+23+13+10$ $10$ times and  $24+17+15+14$ $14$  times ( or $a$ and $b$ times along with $24+23+14+9$ $c$ times for $a,b,c$ to be determined later subject to $a+b+c=24, a+c \leq 23, b+c \leq 9,a \leq 10, b \leq 14,c \leq 9.$) Such a start would limit the possible set of partitions using $24$  used in $\mathcal{B}$ and having chosen those, with or without their multiplicities, there might be enough restrictions to find or rule out a completion.

Alternately, there might be few enough partitions of $46$ into distinct parts (perhaps larger than $7$) to arrive at an impossibility proof.

Comment: "Assign each vertex the partition corresponding to the $i$ such that some $_{}$ uses that vertex." I don't understand that or why it is needed.  The 70 partitions on each side can be assigned to vertices arbitrarily.

Comment: And when this assignment is done, each vertex on that side is labelled by some partition. Likewise each vertex on the other side is labelled by some partition. Then we know which $2j$ vertices to use for the one copy of $K_{jj}.$ The result is (isomorphic to) the original graph. Perhaps it was originally presented in a nice manner that makes it clear it arises from a squared square (if it does). After extracting the partitions and arbitrarily reassigning them it is as if we acted on the graph by some $\sigma \in S_{70} \times S_{70} .$ It might be less nice, but still the same decomposition.

Comment: I understand the situation, but I still think the sentence I quoted is nearly incomprehensible and I suggest you reword it. By the way, there are 47 partitions of 46 into distinct parts from [8,...,24].

Comment: I should have said “consisting of those I” I tried a longer description.