# Squared squares and partitions of $K_{nn}$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

This is inspired by a [recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/340083/a-specific-collection-of-subgraphs-in-k-70-70).

Define a square square sum (**SSS**) of order $n$ to be any partition $$n^2=\sum_1^tc_ii^2 \tag{*}$$ of $n^2$ into square summands. Call it *perfect* if all $c_i \leq 1,$ the summands have distinct sizes.

This question concerns those SSSs which are achieved by certain decompositions.

A [squared square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squaring_the_square) is a tiling of of an $n \times n$ square into smaller integer sided subsquares. If $c_i$ is the number of $i \times i$ subsquares then the SSS (*) is achieved.

A $K_{nn}$ *decomposition* is a partition of $K_{nn}$ into edge disjoint subgraphs, each being a $K_{ii}.$ If $c_i$ is the number of copies of $K_{ii}$ then the SSS (*) is achieved.

If an SSS of order $n$ is achieved by a squared square it is also achieved by a $K_{nn}$ decomposition: Index the vertices of $K_{nn}$ by the rows and columns of the large square. Each  $i \times i$ tile determines a $K_{ii}$ subgraph.

Is the converse true?

> > If a particular SSS (*) is achieved by a $K_{nn}$ decomposition, is it also achieved by a squared square?

I would guess not, but I don't have a counter-example.

The motivating question starts with the perfect SSS $\sum_1^{24}i^2=70^2$ and asks if it can be achieved by a decomposition of $K_{70,70}$ using one copy of $K_{ii}$ for each $i \leq 24.$

If there is indeed such a decomposition, then the answer to my question is no because it is known that the smallest perfect squared square has side $110.$

---

Here are two alternate viewpoints. I am not sure how much they help so consider them optional.

Given an ordering of the vertices from each part of a $K_{nn}$, the edges label the $n^2$ cells of an $n \times n$ square. This is the correspondence we used to make the reduction from a squared square of order $n$ to a $K_{nn}$ decomposition. In the other direction, given a $K_{nn}$ decomposition with an ordering of vertices, assign each $K_{ii}$ its own color and transfer these to the cells of an $n \times n$ square. Then the square is tiled by (possibly disconnected) colored tiles each of the form $S \times T$ where  $S,T \subset \{1,\cdots,n\}$ and $|S|=|T|=i$ for some $i.$ The question then becomes: Given such a tiling by possibly disconnected squares, can the rows and columns be permuted so that the tiling is a squared square. I.E. in each $S \times T,$ both $S$ and $T$ are intervals of size $i.$

---

A $K_{nn}$ decomposition is equivalent to a particular pair $\{\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}\}$ where each of $\mathcal{A,B}$ is a multiset of partitions of $n.$ Assume first that the decomposition is perfect. Assign each vertex the partition corresponding to the $i$ such that some $K_{ii}$ uses that vertex. and let $\mathcal{A,B}$ be the multisets of partitions corresponding to the two vertex classes. The following properties are satisfied:

- Among the $n$ partitions of $\mathcal{A}$ an integer $i$ which appears at all appears $i$ times and similarly for $\mathcal{B}.$

  - Two partitions $\alpha,\beta$ one each from $\mathcal{A,B}$ can share at most one member. Equivalently, there is a partial edge coloring of $K_n$ using Amber and Blue so that two integers appear together in a partition $\alpha \in \mathcal{A}$ only if the corresponding edge is Amber.

The converse is also true. Given such a pair of multisets of partitions, a $K_{n,n}$ decomposition is determined. In the case that the decomposition is not perfect, just use $c_i$ colors for the parts equal to $i$ to distinguish the various $K_{ii}.$

---

It has been suggested that such pairs of multisets of partitions might be useful as a data structure to search for $K_{nn}$ decompositions. If so the second requirement would seem to favor partitions into relatively few parts and high repletion numbers. I've elaborated in an answer (really a long comment) on the [motivating question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/340083/a-specific-collection-of-subgraphs-in-k-70-70).

Comment: $K_{nn}$ can be split into $K_{t,t}+2K_{t,n-t}+K_{n-t,n-t}$ by splitting each side into $t+(n-t)$.  Then any of the parts can be similarly split, and so on recursively.  I think that all such partitions can be labelled to give a squared square.  So an intermediate question is: are there any partitions of $K_{n,n}$ that are not formed by this process?

Comment: To answer my own question, I guess a perfect squared square provides an example, since the recursive process always (at the final step) produces two parts the same.